# Does the AWS SQS connector for Mule (Anypoint) need to be configured to read from a specific region?

Tags: mule

I have a simple flow to read a queue in AWS SQS using Mule's sqs connector:

```
<sqs:config name="Amazon_SQS__Configuration" accessKey="${aws.readonly.accessKey}" secretKey="${aws.readonly.secretKey}" doc:name="Amazon SQS: Configuration"/>
<flow name="status-io-integrationFlow">
    <sqs:receive-messages config-ref="Amazon_SQS__Configuration" queueUrl="< my-Url-To-SQS-Queue >" preserveMessages="true" doc:name="Amazon SQS (Streaming)"/>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

However, I can only get this to work for queues deployed in U.S. East (N. Virginia).  Is there a way to change the region that the sqs connector is using to find the queue?

In US West (Oregon), for example, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.1.9.39.shade.services.sqs.model.QueueDoesNotExistException: The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue; Request ID: a7aad5de-f7da-5b34-9d08-9bfd6cbc6ef0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQS connector is opensource. You can take a look at the code here: https://github.com/mulesoft/sqs-connector

The configuration seems to allow a [region](https://github.com/mulesoft/sqs-connector/blob/develop/src/main/java/org/mule/modules/sqs/Config.java#L65) attribute. This is probably what you are looking for.